# Make the 1st column as header and list its corresponding values using shell script

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

I have a large file contents are as shown below :-

```
Quantity    20589
Quantity    12297
Quantity    100346
Quantity    0
Quantity    141999
Quantity    23662
Quantity    551071
Quantity    72917
Quantity    60460
Quantity    19712
Quantity    35530
Quantity    0
Quantity    29818
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Price   0
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
Discount    100
```

From this file i want to create a new file which should have data as :-

```
Quantity,Price,Discount
20589,0,100
12297,0,100    
100346,0,100
0,0,100    
141999,0,100
23662,0,100
551071,0,100
72917,0,100
60460,0,100
19712,0,100
35530,0,100
0,0,100
29818,0,100
```

i.e. read the original file, the column name should be the header for the new file and the corresponding values listed as shown above.

Please help me to write a new file using shell script.

Comment: Just checking: Whatever produced the data can't be made to produce it in the wanted format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything can be done within single `awk` command by building big array with all data, but if the file is very big you may have problems with available memory. Thus I would do this in several steps:

```
header=$(awk '{print $1}' file | uniq | tr '\n' ',')
printf "${header%?}\n" > output
paste -d, <(awk '$1=="Quantity"{print $2}' file) \
          <(awk '$1=="Price"{print $2}' file) \
          <(awk '$1=="Discount"{print $2}' file) >> output
```

The only tricky part here is removing last comma at the end of the header. I've used `${par%?}` construct for this.

Answer (score 0):

With perl you can have this way,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $file=$ARGV[0];

open my $fId, '<', $file or die "Error opeining file <$file>.";

my @qty = ();
my @price = ();
my @discount = ();

while(<$fId>){
    chomp;

    my @fields = split (/\t/, $_);

    push @qty      , $fields[1] if $fields[0] =~ m/Quantity/;
    push @price    , $fields[1] if $fields[0] =~ m/Price/;
    push @discount , $fields[1] if $fields[0] =~ m/Discount/;
}
close $fId;

print "Quantity,Price,Discount\n";
for(my $i = 0; $i < scalar @qty; $i++){
    print "$qty[$i],$price[$i],$discount[$i]\n";
}
```

You will need to pass filename as argument.

e.g., 
./test.pl input_file